# Help with Division Rules in Modular Arithmetic

Tags: number-theory

I was following a proof, the crux of which came down to understanding that

$$\ \frac{10^k}{10^h}\equiv \frac{-1}{1}\ \mod(p)$$ for some $\ h < k $ and prime $p$, provided that

$\ {10^k}\equiv {-1}\ \mod(p)$ and $\ {10^h}\equiv {1}\ \mod(p)$
are already known to be true.

I know that there are very specific rules for modular division (although I am ignorant to them), so I tried out another example

$$\ \frac{4^3}{4^2}\equiv \frac{-1}{1}\ \mod(5)$$

in which, sure enough, the "division" turned out to be true. Please help me out, what the heck is this sorcery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $10^h\equiv1\pmod p$ and $10^k\equiv-1\pmod p$ where $h<k$ then
$$-1\equiv 10^k=(10^h)(10^{k-h})\equiv(1)(10^{k-h})=10^{k-h}
\pmod p.$$
Thus $10^{k-h}\equiv-1\pmod p$.

Note that I have used standard facts about modular multiplication
here, but nothing about "division".

Comment: Thank you very much! That looks much nicer haha